# How to remap windows extended numeric keyboard for M2 Macbook

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I have remapped most of the keys to get them to work like a normal Windows keyboard using Karabiner. However, the numeric keyboard (right-hand side of the full keyboard) isn't being fully recognized by Mac and is giving error sounds when I type. The error sounds don't bother me too much as I can just turn off sounds on the Macbook, however when I type two numbers quickly together (i.e. 1 and 2, I get 1212 vs. 12) which is strange, and it only occurs when typing them quickly together.

When using the numbers directly above the normal keyboard (below the function keys) it works as normal.

I used the accessibility on-screen keyboard to see if I could debug, and found initially that the right-hand side numeric keys weren't recognized at all, so I remapped them using Karabiner, but it didn't fix the issue.

Does anyone have a solution to this (either the error sounds or registering the keys twice)?

For context, I am using an M2 Macbook Air (2022) and [Windows Microsoft Bluetooth keyboard](https://a.co/d/1Guk37a).

Comment: I've got an old Dell PC keyboard that came with one of Dell's Optiplex units and all the keys on the numeric keypad work fine, including PrtScr, Scroll Lock, etc which map to function keys. And, having worked in PC support for many years I usually use an old PC keyboard with no problems. So *are you sure the keyboard is not defective?*

Comment: Make sure you have Mouse Keys in accessibility settings turned OFF, as this disables a numpad when it is on.

Comment: Do the numpad issues occur with Karabiner off?

Comment: Note that even on a Mac, the numpad & 'above qwerty' numbers are recognised differently & have different codes. Having said that, I've never needed to remap a Win keyboard to work on a Mac [aside from the obvious 'no equivalent' keys.]

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have mouse keys turned off and the numpad issues do occur with Karabiner off as well. The keyboard works perfectly fine with my other windows laptop and I even tried a Dell wired keyboard and it has the same issues

Comment: To note, the numeric keys do work, it's just the double typing issue is what I am trying to fix